# I deleted windows and I am having trouble merging the unused partition

Tags: partitioning

I tried Ubuntu. I like it, I cleared the partition that had windows on it, now I can't seem to merge my /dev/sda5 ext4 partition with my unallocated partition. Ubuntu is installed on a 42 Gig partition, but I have an unallocated partition of 320 Gigs and I would like to merge the two.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to AskUbuntu. What do you mean by "i can't ... merge"? Why not? What happens when you try? How do you do it? Adding a screenshot of the current layout would be great.

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrw7b.png

Comment: wow I'm tired. Not sure exactly;y what I need to be doing, I have tried resizing the partitions, but not sure how to make them one

Answer (score 0):

Merging won't work if the partitions you want to merge are not adjacent. If you have a partition in between, you might be able to move this partition first. But be careful; if this is somehow your boot partition, you might break GRUB; it's wise to have a LiveCD or usb stick lying around to reinstall GRUB afterwards.

Comment: Basically I would like my harddrive back into one partition, as I had it on Windows previous to installing Ubuntu

Comment: Entirely one partition is not really recommended. You would preferably like to have a SWAP partition as well; this doesn't have to be big (10GB or so). Linux will use your SWAP parition whenever it runs out of physical RAM. While SWAP is giganourmously slow, it prevents all kinds of nasty "out of memory"-errors. Btw, it looks like if you're trying to merge a primary partition (/dev/sda1) with an extended partiton (/dev/sda3). I'm not sure whether that is possible.